# Why are GObject properties numbered from 1?

Tags: c, gobject

In all of the GObject examples involving properties, I see property #0 set aside for some reason. ([Example](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-class-install-properties))

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html):

> The property id of 0 is treated specially by GObject and it should not be used to store a GParamSpec.